# Why does fine-tuned vgg-16 perform better than fine-tuned inception-v3 for the same dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a dataset of plant images I collected in the field. I trained a fine-tuned inception-v3 and a vgg16 model with this dataset.

**This was same for both datasets**

```
opt = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.09)
# Fine-tuning with a small learning rate
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',optimizer = opt,
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**VGG16**

I froze all the layers in the base model and trained for 50 epochs for warmup.
Then I unfroze layers starting from layer index 15 and trained for 100 epochs.

This is the result.
[image]

[image]

**inceptionv3**

I froze all layers in the base model and trained for 20 epochs. Next, I unfrooze all layers below layer index 249 as stated in [keras documentation](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/docs/templates/applications.md#fine-tune-inceptionv3-on-a-new-set-of-classes) and trained for 100 more epochs.

This is the result.

[image]
[image]

Its' clear that vgg16 is performing better than inceptionv3. What is the reason for this?

Comment: It depends on many things, like the setup of the optimizer, learning rate, learning rate scheduler and so on. However, vgg16 has a greater number of parameters than inceptionv3, so it's easier to fit the new data to some extent because of the excess capacity.

Comment: One more thing to add is that the depth of inceptionv3 (159) is way deeper than VGG16 (23). So, it is possible that we need to fine-tune inceptionv3 for more epochs to make the gradients flow effectively toward the shallow layers.